# delete row if string found vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete rows if the excel file does not contain a certain word.

I loop through the cells within column B and check if the cell value contains this string and if not then I will delete it.

However, I am getting an error saying **Delete method of range class failed**.

```
Sub macro()

Dim i As Integer, intValueToFind As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("RAW DATA (2)")

For i = 1 To 500    ' Revise the 500 to include all of your values

    If InStr(Cells(i, 2).Value, "Error") = False Or InStr(Cells(i, 2).Value, "No credentials") = False Or InStr(Cells(i, 2).Value, "Connection Failed") = False Then
        ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your methods a bit.

'.EntireRow' Is the property of a Range, not a Row.

So where you have:

```
ws.rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

You should put something like:

```
ws.Range("B"&i).EntireRow.Delete
```

But really, you could simplify this with one of the .Row methods, which is just Delete. So, you could alternatively just say:

```
ws.rows(i).Delete
```

I've tested both and confirmed syntax is correct; I can't see any other issues with your code.

Comment: I have no got an a subscript out of range when assigning the worksheet to a variable

Comment: @Johnathon64 Did you change how you assigned the worksheet to a variable? Because I didn't require you to do that. Is this an error you saw before? Make sure your ws name "Raw Data (2)" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Modify all of your string comparisons to be closer to,

```
    If NOT InStr(1, " error no credentials connection failed ", lcase(Cells(i, 2).Value), vbTextCompare) Then
```

Comment: Just tried to copy and paste your solution but got errors

Comment: my apologies. I wrote that off the top of my head and made an error. [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Autofilter is more efficient than looping

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Sheet1.Range("a1:c35").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>error"
    Sheet1.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    Sheet1.UsedRange.AutoFilter
'repeat for each value
End Sub
```